# Emacs EIN: ein: [warn] ein:jupyter-process-lines: cannot find jupyter

Tags: jupyter-notebook, emacs

I was trying to replace jupyter by emacs's  EIN mode, but got the error:
`ein:jupyter-process-lines: cannot find jupyter`
whenever I am tring to call `ein:jupyter-server-start` and `ein:stop.`
Any suggetions on how should I proceed from here, thanks in advance!

Some guidance on how ein works and how to resolve my question would be great.